# Using regular Skype on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, skype

In the anniversary update to Windows 10, Microsoft got rid of regular Skype and only has Skype Preview. Is there a way I can get back regular Skype?

Comment: Yes; Download the desktop client from the Skype website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can. Visit [skype.com](http://www.skype.com). It will detect that you are running Windows 10 and will tell you that you can use Skype Preview but it will not stop you from downloading an ordinary Skype. This download is a bootstrapper which will get you the actual Skype installer.

Alternatively, you can always get a [full Skype installer from Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Fax-Telephony/Skype.shtml). This is useful if you save the installers of your apps in the even that you reinstalled Windows.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could get a portable skype installation from [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/sportable). sPortable assists you with running Skype™ in a portable way without needing to install it in Windows. It's packaged as a portable app so you can communicate on the go.

Its pretty a smart way to run Skype without uninstallation of Metro Skype in later editions of Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , The anniversary update to windows 10 removed the regular skype, but we can install the skype directly and use it instead of using skype preview.